# VBA- Ammend code from Copy and paste to destination

Tags: vba, excel

my code is running really slowly and I'm trying to fasten it. The only way I can think of is to do without the last bit of code which does copy, select,paste twice for two different target worksheets. Was wondering if I'm able to change it to something like Destination:= ____ & ____ instead of selecting and pasting twice?

```
    Sub compare()
'compare if the values of two ranges are the same
'Select workbook to prevent mismatch error
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

Workbooks("Compare.xlsm").Activate
    Dim referencesheetname, newsheetname, outputsheetname As String
    referencesheetname = "Reference"
    newsheetname = "New"

    Dim range1, range2 As Range
    'define the variables
    Dim referencesheetcols As Integer
    Dim range1rows, range1cols, range2rows, range2cols, testrows, testcols, i, j, p, q As Long
    Dim bMatches, rowmatched As Boolean
    Dim product As String
    'Define names for easy reference
    product = "Ethylene"
    'Set range you wish the macro to search up till
    newsheetcols = 3000
    referencesheetcols = 3000
    'How many rows and columns should we compare?
    'Set testcols to 150 to test whole range
    testrows = 1
    testcols = 200

    'Set p for position to place data at (i.e. if p=1, data will be pasted)
    p = Sheets(referencesheetname).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    q = Sheets("Datasheet").UsedRange.Rows.Count


    'Pasted table range data starts from row 7
    For l = 1 To newsheetcols
        'ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(newsheetname).Select
        'only test if correct product down column B
        If CStr(Sheets(newsheetname).Rows(l).Cells(1, 2).Value) = product Then

            rowmatched = False
            For k = 5 To referencesheetcols

                'bmatch = False
                'Define range compare rows 6 onwards for both sheets
                Set range1 = Sheets(referencesheetname).Rows(k)
                Set range2 = Sheets(newsheetname).Rows(l)

                ' count the rows and columns in each of the ranges
                range1rows = range1.Rows.Count
                range1cols = range1.Columns.Count
                range2rows = range2.Rows.Count
                range2cols = range2.Columns.Count

                'Check if ranges are the same dimension?
                bMatches = (range1rows = range2rows And range1cols = range2cols)

                'if same dimensions loop through the cells
                If bMatches Then

                    For i = 1 To testrows
                        For j = 1 To testcols

                            If (range1.Cells(i, j).Value <> range2.Cells(i, j).Value) Then
                                 'Conclude that range dimension is not the same
                                 bMatches = False
                                 i = testrows
                                 j = testcols
                                 'Exit loops
                            End If
                        Next
                    Next
                End If

                'If ranges of two comparison sheets are the same
                If bMatches Then
                    rowmatched = True
                    k = referencesheetcols
                End If

                'Sheets(outputsheetname).Cells(1, 1).Value = rowmatched
                'Set place to paste data
                If (Not (rowmatched) And k = referencesheetcols) Then
                'Copy and paste specified number of columns
                    range2.Resize(1, 300).Copy
                    Sheets(referencesheetname).Cells(p, 1).Offset(2, 0).Select
                    ActiveSheet.Paste
                    p = p + 1
                    Sheets("Datasheet").Activate
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(q, 1).Offset(2, 1).Select
                    ActiveSheet.Paste
                    q = q + 1
                End If
                Next
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I've no idea how much, if any, it would speed things up - all your variables, except the last on the declaration line are Variants.  **Dim range1, range2 As Range** - range2 is a Range, range1 is a Variant.  **Dim bMatches, rowmatched As Boolean** - rowmatched is boolean, bMatches is Variant.

Comment: The extent of your loops - newsheetcols, referencesheetcols are set to an arbitrary figure rather than the exact number needed.  If newsheetcols only needs to be 5 you're wasting a whole load of time looping through the other 2995 iterations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like below should be ok to change to copy - destination.

```
range2.Resize(1, 300).Copy Destination:=Sheets(referencesheetname).Cells(p, 1).Offset(2, 0)
```

Although if you really wanted to speed up your code I would say you would need to read the range into an array and then do your processing on the array. looking at the sheet is costly in terms of cpu time, selecting should be avoided where ever possible

You could also turn calculation off and just recalc when you need it too. You could also look up "WITH"'s as these can speed it up a bit too

Comment: I was thinking of having two destinations. i.e. range2.Resize(1, 300).Copy Destination:=Sheets(referencesheetname).Cells(p, 1).Offset(2, 0) & Sheets(Datasheet).Cells(q, 1).Offset(2, 0). Is this possible?

Comment: As far as I am aware you would have to use two of the above lines of code

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "read the range into an array and then do your processing on the array"?

Comment: the second comments where are about some optimisations you could use to the loops in the first part of your code. It may be worth while googling "VBA Arrays" if you would like to learn more about arrays. essentially it means reading the data into a variable and then looping the variable (rather than looping the sheet), and referencing the array rather than the sheet throughout your code.